# php session destroy issue

Tags: php, session

the problem is the session isn't destroyed when you logout so that you can still access some page that you ought not to access it, i placed an echo statement containing the `login_user` of the array `$_SESSION` and whenever you logout and paste the link of that page the login_user was printed successfully what's wrong with my code,I've even tried other ways than unset such as changing the value of `login_user` to "" nothing is changed.

login page code(named:HomeTest.php)

```
<?php
  require("./config.php");
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    session_start();
.... 
  if($count == 1) {
  $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
  header("location: welcome.php");
  }else {
  $error = "Your username or password is incorrect";
  }
}
```

session.php :

```
<?php
   require_once('./config.php');
   session_start();
   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select username from accounts where username = '$user_check' ");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $login_session = $row['username'];
   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:HomeTest.php");
   }
?>
```

logout.php :

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if(session_destroy()) {
      unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
      header("Location: login.php");
   }
?>
```

another page that shouldn't be accessed unless you're signed in :

```
<?php
    require_once("./config.php");
    require_once('./session.php');
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
        header("location:HomeTest.php");
        die("");
    }
?>
```

Comment: In `logout.php` add `session_destroy()` This will destroy your entire session values

Comment: @FairyDancer I've just done that and still nothing is changed.

Comment: can you put following code in your `HomeTest.php` which is login page. And code as follow `<?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); ?>` let me know the output of this code after logout

Comment: Array
(
    [login_user] => Haytham
)

Comment: is this showing after logout?

Comment: @FairyDancer yes :/ .

Answer (score 2):

Use following code for **logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");
?>
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

the probleme is because

```
if(session_destroy()) {}
```

does not return true

you can change that condition by

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  session_unset();
```